# How to pass a percent sign to a msgbox?

Tags: autohotkey, percentage, variable-names

Using `^w::MsgBox, 100%` returns:

> This parameter contains a variable name missing.

But the same line without `%` sign works. How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must escape certain characters, such as `%` , `,` , `;`. To escape them use the ` character.

```
 ^w::MsgBox, 100`%
```